# ng-click pass value to function

Tags: angularjs

I would like to pass a value/integer to a controller function when a button is clicked.   For example:

```
<button ng-click="setTimer(5)"></button>
```

When clicked would send the integer value to the controller

```
$scope.setTimer = function (value) {
   // Do something here
}
```

Currently If I click any of the buttons (3, 5, 10, 15) No event registers on the console. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

http://run.plnkr.co/B7zPGD79BqHz6ebB/

http://plnkr.co/edit/TjzfHRLSqKpZcfGWQNd3?p=preview

Comment: Could you please tell what's your problem, the code you've just shown should work. Checkout the fiddle I've created http://jsfiddle.net/lpiepiora/Xb4yH/1/

Comment: as @lpiepiora said, the code you provided works, you can even use models or variables in it if you want( example here http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/DfhTZ/ )
What problem did you encounter ?

Comment: @DotDotDot I'm doing pretty much what you fiddled but for some reason it just wont' work.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that's working for me. Setup a bit different than  lpiepiora, but nearly the same - http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/h28sN/

Comment: Thanks all got it working.  The Button's were not in the scope. Stupid mistake.

Comment: @aozkan exactly, I was going to say that but you spotted it before, good luck with your project ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons were not in-scope.  Hence the event never made it to the controller.

Thanks for everyone's help.